# Filter in WordPress/Woocommerce to disable Cash-on-Delivery for a specific shipping zone

Tags: filter, woocommerce, payment

I am trying to set a filter that would calculate the cash-on-delivery payment when the customer selects a specific shipping zone (for out-of-town deliveries). I'm using the `Table Rates` Plug-in.

I was looking at this code (https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/1499) at the answer by maxrice, but I can't adapt it to suit my needs:

My `zone_id` to exclude COD payment is `table_rate-3`.

Comment: Maybe you could explain some more what you've tried, and exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see looking at http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Gateway_COD.html the native woocommerce COD class has no filters or actions you can hook into for your problem.

What you could do is disable the woocommerce native COD payment gateway and make your own. This link here provides a bit of a template for making your own payment gateway. 
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-payment-gateway-plugin-base/ 
You could paste the woocommerce COD class in here (where it says `// Go wild in here` on line 31) and make changes as necessary. I imagine you'll mostly need to make changes to the `is_available()` function. You put that code down in either your themes functions.php file or better yet make your own plugin.